Roll back to a previous changelist and replay a change
I have some automated testing that runs heavy checks only on files that are checked out in perforce and lighter checks for everything else. I want to locally reproduce an issue that was caught by tests in the past and was subsequently fixed. I need to get my client into a state where it reflects the repo at the point in time where the issue was detected and the files in the offending changelist are checked out.
Imagine I have a depot with the following changelist history
CL 3 <-- Workspace is here
CL 2 <-- Problem is here
CL 1

My workspace is currently on CL 3. I want to roll back to CL 2 and open all files in that changelist for edit. Either of the following scenarios are acceptable:

Workspace is on CL 2, files from CL 2 are opened for edit and show up as unmodified
Workspace is on CL 1, changes from CL 2 are re-applied, files from CL 2 are opened for edit and show up as modified

Rolling back is easy: p4 sync ...@2. But how do I open all files from CL 2?
I considered rolling back to CL 1, then copying the files from CL 2, but I don't know how to copy only the files from CL 2 and not every file in the depot at the point in time CL 2 was submitted.
Rolling back to Cl1 and merging CL 2 doesn't work either
p4 merge -F "@2,@2"
All revision(s) already integrated.


Start with a clean workspace (nothing opened).  (Obviously if you have anything important in progress you'll want to p4 shelve it first!)
p4 revert //...

Now sync your workspace to the state as of changelist 2:
p4 sync @2

Now open all files affected by changelist 2 itself:
p4 -F %depotFile% files @=2 | p4 -x - edit

Note that depending on what exactly you want to do with those files, opening them for edit might not be the right thing (for example, if you wanted to roll them back and one of the files was deleted in changelist 2, edit isn't the command that'll let you put it back to how it was in changelist 1 -- for that you'd want p4 undo @2).
